# Getting rich relation list populated when fetching entity neo4j spring

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using spring and spring-neo4j-data and i try to fetch with the entity also the relations.

I have File Entity

```
@NodeEntity(label="File")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FileNeo4jEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Getter
@Setter
private Long id;

@Getter
@Setter
private String name;

@Getter
@Setter
private String path;

@Getter
@Setter
@Relationship(type = "HAS_PROPERTY",direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private List<HasPropertyNeo4jRelationEntity> properties;

public void addProperty(HasPropertyNeo4jRelationEntity relation) {
    if (this.properties == null) {
        this.properties = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.properties.add(relation);
}
```

The Relation entity

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="HAS_PROPERTY")
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
public class HasPropertyNeo4jRelationEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long relationshipId;

@Getter
@Setter
@StartNode
private FileNeo4jEntity file;

@Getter
@Setter
@EndNode
private PropertyNeo4jEntity property;

@Getter
@Setter
@Property
int value;
}
```

And the Property Entity

```
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)
@NoArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity(label = "Property")
public class PropertyNeo4jEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Getter
@Setter
private Long id;

@Getter
@Setter
@Relationship(type = "HAS_PROPERTY")
List<FileNeo4jEntity> files;

@Getter
@Setter
private String categoryName;

}
```

When i fetch from repository a property by categoryName i also get the files List populated.
When i fetch from repository a file by Name (doesn't really matter by what) the properties list is always null. I even treid something like this but no effect

```
@Query("MATCH (f:File {name: {0} })<-[r:HAS_PROPERTY]-(p) RETURN f,r,p")
FileNeo4jEntity findByNameWithRelations(String name);
```

How could i get also the properties list also populated when i fetch a file entity?